# How can I use abaqus cae without graphical user interface and with a database model?

Tags: python, abaqus

How, can I run an Abaqus cae without graphic user interface, but with a model database (cae file), and a python script in a command line?

I tried this command:
abaqus cae database=test.cae script=test2.py, it works well but with graphic user interface, However I am trying the two commands:

1. abaqus cae database=test.cae noGUI=test2.py
2. abaqus cae noGUI=test2.py -- test.cae

And they don't work, 
Anybody could help me?

Answer (score 2):

The second command should provide the behavior you're looking for. You didn't describe what happens when you run it, but I'm assuming your script is failing because it probably is relying on the CAE file already being loaded. In the second scenario you'll need to load the CAE file yourself. This is from the Abaqus Scripting Reference Manual - Python Commands, under the `Mdb` section:

[image: Abaqus mdb.openMdb documentation]

One way your script could use this:

```
import sys
from abaqus import *

# Get the cae file path and name from the last command line argument
cae_file_path = sys.argv[-1]

openMdb(cae_file_path)

# And then find the appropriate model in mdb.models, your key may be different
# and may need to be also supplied from the command line if it changes between
# CAE files
model = mdb.models['Model-1']
```